# Codeigniter ajax POST cannot insert to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Help me Im stuck

This is what I want to achieved:

when user click the button, it will:

1. check if the user id exist?
2. if exist display pop up error message
3. if user id not exist, do the following:

   - pop up the dialog
   - insert into users table
   - insert into user details table
   - sending email

I stuck at point 3, point 2 & 3 (cannot insert to both table)

**controller**

```
function beforeSave() {
        $this->load->model('admin/user_detail_model', 'user_detail_model');
        $this->load->model('admin/es_user_model', 'es_user_model');

        $noPengenalan = $this->input->post('noPengenalan');

        $userIdAvailable = $this->individu_model->check_if_userid_exists($noPengenalan);

        if (count($userIdAvailable) > 0) {
            echo "exist";
        }else{
            $tamatPassport = $this->input->post('tamatPassport');

            $user_detail = $this->user_detail_model->save(array(
                'USER_SEX' => $this->input->post('jantina'),
                'USER_NATIONALITY' => $this->input->post('warganegara'),
                'USER_ID' => $this->input->post('noPengenalan'),
                'USER_NEGARA' => $this->input->post('negara'),
                'USER_PASSPORT_EXPIRED' => "to_date('$tamatPassport','dd/mm/yyyy')",false,
                'USER_ADDRESS' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
                'USER_ADDRESS2' => $this->input->post('alamat2'),
                'USER_ADDRESS3' => $this->input->post('alamat3'),
                'USER_CITY' => $this->input->post('bandar'),
                'USER_NEGERI' => $this->input->post('negeri'),
                'USER_POSTCODE' => $this->input->post('poskod'),
                'USER_NOTEL' => $this->input->post('noTel'),
                'USER_NOTEL_HP' => $this->input->post('noHp'),
                'USER_NOTEL_OFFICE' => $this->input->post('noPejabat'),
                'USER_EMAIL' => $this->input->post('email')
            ));

            $es_user = $this->es_user_model->save(array(
                'USER_ID' => $this->input->post('USER_ID'),
                'USER_NAME' => $this->input->post('USER_NAME'),
                'EU_ICTYPE' => $this->input->post('EU_ICTYPE')
            ));

            // send email
            $this->load->library('email','email');

            $config = array(
              'protocol' => 'smtp',
              'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
              'smtp_port' => 465,
              'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
              'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx', // change it to yours
              'mailtype' => 'html',
              'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
              'wordwrap' => TRUE
            );

            $data['noPengenalan'] = $this->input->post('noPengenalan');
            $data['namaPenuh'] = $this->input->post('namaPenuh');

            $today = date('m/d/Y');
            $new = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($today)));

            $data['date_register'] = $today;
            $data['date_expired'] = $new;

            $message = $this->load->view('profile/individu/email_activation', $data, TRUE);
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
            $this->email->to('yyyy@gmail.com');// change it to yours
            $this->email->subject('Permohonan ID Individu - ' . $noPengenalan);
            $this->email->message($message);
            $this->email->send();

            echo "continue";
        }
    }
```

**model**

```
public function save($data)
    {        
        $this->db->set('USER_SEX', $data['USER_SEX']);
        $this->db->set('USER_NATIONALITY', $data['USER_NATIONALITY']);
        $this->db->set('USER_ID', $data['USER_ID']);
        $this->db->set('USER_NEGARA', $data['USER_NEGARA']);
        $this->db->set('USER_PASSPORT_EXPIRED',$data['USER_PASSPORT_EXPIRED']);
        $this->db->set('USER_ADDRESS', $data['USER_ADDRESS']);
        $this->db->set('USER_ADDRESS2', $data['USER_ADDRESS2']);
        $this->db->set('USER_ADDRESS3', $data['USER_ADDRESS3']);
        $this->db->set('USER_CITY', $data['USER_CITY']);
        $this->db->set('USER_NEGERI', $data['USER_NEGERI']);
        $this->db->set('USER_POSTCODE', $data['USER_POSTCODE']);
        $this->db->set('USER_NOTEL', $data['USER_NOTEL']);
        $this->db->set('USER_NOTEL_HP', $data['USER_NOTEL_HP']);
        $this->db->set('USER_NOTEL_OFFICE', $data['USER_NOTEL_OFFICE']);
        $this->db->set('USER_EMAIL', $data['USER_EMAIL']);

        $this->db->insert('USER_DETAILS'); 
    }
```

**ajax**

```
function test(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                jantina: $('#jantina').val(),
                warganegara: $('#warganegara').val(),
                noPengenalan: $("#noPengenalan").val(),
                negara: $('#negara').val(),
                tamatPassport: $('#tamatPassport').val(),
                alamat: $('#alamat').val(),
                alamat2: $('#alamat2').val(),
                alamat3: $('#alamat3').val(),
                bandar: $('#bandar').val(),
                negeri: $('#negeri').val(),
                poskod: $('#poskod').val(),
                noTel: $('#noTel').val(),
                noHp: $('#noHp').val(),
                noPejabat: $('#noPejabat').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                // es_users
                namaPenuh: $('#namaPenuh').val(),
                jenPengenalan: $('#jenPengenalan').val()
            },
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/individu/main/beforeSave/",
            // dataType: 'text',
            success: function(response) {
                        if (response == 'exist') {
                            bootbox.dialog({
                                title: "Informasi Pengguna",
                                message: "<?php echo '<p>1. Sila log masuk ke dalam Sistem. <b><u><a href=' . base_url() . 'index.php/sso/main' . '>Log Masuk</a></u></b></p>'
                                . '<p>2. Sila reset kata laluan anda. <b><u>Resit Kata Laluan</u></b></p>'
                                . '<p>3. Jika langkah (1) atau (2) tidak berjaya, sila hadir ke cawangan LHDNM yang berdekatan untuk '
                                . 'kemaskini emel.</u></b></p>'
                                . '<br>'; ?>"
                            });
                        }else{
                            bootbox.dialog({
                                title: "Pop up Message",
                                message: "<?php echo '<p>Sila hadir ke cawangan LHDN yang berdekatan untuk mendapatkan pin keselamatan/kata laluan</p>'
                                .'<p>Anda diberi tempoh 3 bulan untuk membuat pengaktifan akaun.</p>'
                                .'<p>Terima kasih karena berurusan dengan pihak LDHN M. Kerjasama Anda amat dihargai.</p>'; ?>"
                            });
                        }
                    }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you load `individu_model` for `$userIdAvailable = $this->individu_model->check_if_userid_exists($noPengenalan);` in `beforeSave()` ?

Comment: yes, I have loaded it in the constructor, everything is fine except for inserting the tables

Comment: Do you get any error when inserting the tables?

Comment: I didn't get any error, how to trace error inserting when using ajax post?

Comment: what is controller name??

Comment: controller name is `main` ... `individu` is the directory

Comment: When you do the submission and the AJAX method runs do you get any errors in the browser's console?